# Website Doesn't redirect correctly

Tags: macos, network, dns

I have recently created a blog and hosted that on a freehosting website.

- domain is purchased from hostgater
- Website is hosted on freehosting.
- On hostgather nameserver has been updated as per suggested by freehosting.

**Probem**

- If I open from my andriod mobile it shows correct page.
- My mac shows the page from hostgater which ask me to update the nameserver.

**Wesbite**: allabouthadoop.net

```
C02V48Y7HTD5:~ gaurang.shah$ nslookup allabouthadoop.net
Server:     2001:1970:c06e:c0::94
Address:    2001:1970:c06e:c0::94#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   allabouthadoop.net
Address: 192.185.0.218

C02V48Y7HTD5:~ gaurang.shah$ nslookup 192.185.0.218
Server:     2001:1970:c06e:c0::94
Address:    2001:1970:c06e:c0::94#53

** server can't find 218.0.185.192.in-addr.arpa.: NXDOMAIN
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use **nslookup** to test reachability on macOS. Try **scutil** instead:

```
scutil -r www.apple.com
Reachable
scutil -r 192.185.0.218
Reachable,Directly Reachable Address
scutil -r allabouthadoop.net
Reachable
```

Then you'll need to check if the ports you want are open once you've verified network reachability (and if you have to go through a router or the address is directly reachable on a local subnet to your Mac). I use https://brew.sh to get **nmap** installed easily.

```
/usr/local/bin/nmap allabouthadoop.net
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-09-02 15:10 HST
Nmap scan report for allabouthadoop.net (195.201.179.80)
Host is up (0.23s latency).
rDNS record for 195.201.179.80: free-hosting-clients.freehosting.com
Not shown: 985 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
21/tcp   open  ftp
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
80/tcp   open  http
110/tcp  open  pop3
143/tcp  open  imap
443/tcp  open  https
465/tcp  open  smtps
554/tcp  open  rtsp
587/tcp  open  submission
993/tcp  open  imaps
995/tcp  open  pop3s
7070/tcp open  realserver
9100/tcp open  jetdirect
9103/tcp open  jetdirect

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 14.66 seconds
```

Comment: sorry for the confustion, I think my question was not correct as per my problem. I have updated the question.

Comment: @GaurangShah Ahh - so it's not redirecting properly on Mac browser and is on android browser? You might check a couple browsers to see if the redirect is broken in just your main browser? Let's leave this up - I'll edit if I can think of something else